# Homology Groups of a CW-complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

We have the following CW-complex inside a Complex Projective space:

One $0$-cell,

Three $2$-cells A,B,C. Their closure is made by adding the $0$-cell,

Three $4$-cells. The closure of the first one is made by adding A,B and the $0$-cell, the closure of the second one is made by adding A,C and the $0$-cell, the closure of the third one is made by adding B,C and the $0$-cell,

One $6$-cell, its closure is made by adding everything listed above.

We want to know:

$1)$ Can I deduce this is not a smooth variety since there are three $2$-cells attached to a single $0$-cell?

$2)$ Can I deduce the homology groups with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$? I don't understand if their dimensions listed from bottom to top only in even degrees are $(1,0,0,1)$ or $(1,3,3,1)$.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: write down the chain complex which computes the cellular homology. You should see quickly which dimensions are correct. (I also suspect the answer to your first question is no: having "too many" cells meet at point can be fixed by attaching your way out of the problem [think n-torus]. I'm not certain which way the actual answer goes, though, so I won't be posting.)

Comment: There are no non-trivial differentials in celluar complex that computes the CW homology, so $H^0X=X^6X=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H^2X=H^4X=\mathbb{Z}^3$. Since everything is torsion free this calculates the homology and shows that it is in fact a candidate to be a Poincare duality complex. I think your description of the cells is meant to reflect attaching data, but I don't have enough experience to be able to interpret it confidently. It sounds like you are describing a triple of degree 1 whitehead products, which would give you $X\cong S^2\times S^2\times S^2$.

Comment: @Tyrone I'm describing the Schubert variety given by the permutation $(1,2,3,4)\to (3,1,4,2)$ inside the Complete Flag Variety $Fl_4(\mathbb C)$. I need to prove it is singular cause Poincarè Duality fails, but as long as I can see it holds.

Comment: Can you possibly provide any more information on the attaching data?

Comment: @Tyrone Yes! This is the complete question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880008/singular-schubert-variety-in-fl-4-mathbb-c