# Singular Schubert Variety in $Fl_4(\mathbb C)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, schubert-calculus

Consider the Complete Flag Variety $Fl_4(\mathbb C)$ and its Schubert Variety given by the permutation $(1234) \to (3142)$, i.e. its highest dimension cell can be parametrized by $$\begin{bmatrix}
    *       & 1 & 0  & 0 \\
    *       & 0 & *  & 1 \\
    1 & 0 &0& 0 \\
    0   & 0 & 1  & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

We want to show that it is a singular variety in two ways:

$1)$ Showing that Poincaré Duality fails,

$2)$ Using the standard equations defining the Schubert varieties: 
$$X=\{V_{\bullet}\ | dim (E_i \cap V_j) \geq w_{i,j}\ \forall i,j \in(1,4)\} $$
where $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset E_3 \subset E_4$ is the standard flag of a fixed base, and $w_{i,j}$is the rank of the principal (i,j) minor of the $4 \times 4$ permutation matrix $w$ associated to our permutation.

**Thoughts:**
$1)$ Since there are one $0$-cell, three $2$-cells, three $4$-cells and one $6$-cell I don't get why Poincaré Duality should fail.

$2)$ The only thing I can think of is to take the several equations defining the flag and the several planes defining the Schubert Variety and intersect everything, then derive and find a singularity, but I guess this is much much complicated! There must be something simpler I'm not thinking of.

Thanks!

Comment: There are singular spaces with Poincaré duality, for example a projective curve with a cusp.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet we are explicitally required to show that Poincaré duality fails, but I can't see that!

Comment: Not an expert but here are some thoughts : 
For 1) did you try to compute the intersection pairing ? The original Poincaré duality theorem says that the intersection matrix is unimodular, so this might fails.
For 2) the Schubert cell is smooth iff the 0-cell is a smooth point, so I would try to compute the tangent space at this point and see what you get. Not really helpful sorry but this is all I can think right now ...

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet in 1), do you mean that the matrix in which the position $i,j$ is $\sigma_i \cdot \sigma_j$ where $\sigma_k$ is the Schubert cells basis of the Cohomology Ring has determinant $\pm 1$?

Comment: Yes this is the only possiblity I can see... (but I haven't checked the CW structure). Good luck !